# Perl - reference of an array

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, sftp

I am using this module : [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign)
and i am trying to use the "more" option with multiple arguments.

the document says

```
    more => [@more_ssh_args] 

Note that this option expects a single command argument or a reference to an array of arguments. For instance:

  more => '-v'         # right
  more => ['-v']       # right
  more => "-c $cipher"    # wrong!!!
  more => [-c => $cipher] # right
```

but i can't get it to work.

Basically, i have all my arguments in an array called @sftp_args 
you can see the data here for example (with \@ and @):

```
print Dumper(@sftp_opts);
$VAR1 = '-v';
$VAR2 = '-q';
----------------------------------
print Dumper(\@sftp_opts);
$VAR1 = [
          '-v',
          '-q'
        ];
```

in my SFTP code, i've tried many options, like :

```
more => [\@sftp_opts];
more => \@sftp_opts;
more => \[@sftp_opts];
```

but nothing works :(

any help please ?

thanks,

regards,

Comment: define "nothing works", does perl give an error or the SFTP connection fails?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to understand is what is going on in the background. These *options* are passed to the class constructor as an array. Arguments are always passed as an array.

Thus, if I have a subroutine (or a *method* or a *class constructor*, they're all subroutines underneath their dressed up exterior), and I pass in a call like this:

```
foo (
    -bar => "far",
    -foo => "boo", 
 );
```

I am actually doing this:

```
foo( "bar", "far", "foo", "boo" );
```

And my subroutine is getting this:

```
sub foo {
    my %args = @_;   # Arguments are passed in array @_ no matter what the syntax is
    ...
```

Let' say I can pass a *more* option which is a reference to an array:

```
 foo (
    -bar => "far",
    -foo => "boo",
    -more => [
        -fubar => "bufar",
        -barfu => "farbu",
    ],
};
```

What I'm passing is an array like this:

```
 sub foo (
    my @array = _@;

    say $array[0];   # -bar
    say $array[1];   # far
    say $array[2];   # -foo
    say $array[3];   # boo
    say $array[4];   # -more
    say $array[5];   # ARRAY reference

    say $array[5]->[0]; # -fubar
    say $array[5]->[1]; # bufar
    say $array[5]->[2]; # -barfu
    say $array[5]->[3]; # farbu
```

I want to emphasize how *simple* all o this is. Sometimes a person can over think a situation, and get flustered. If you need to pass an array reference to `-more`, all it means is that the next element of your array after `-more` is an array reference. Therefore, you want to pass in an array reference. This is the correct way to do it:

```
-more => \@more_args;
```

Or you can give it an actual list of options using `[...]` to represent an anonymous array reference much like how I did it for subroutine `foo` above.

Here's what you can do if you suspect you're not passing your array of parameters (remember, it's just an array) correctly to your subroutine: Create a temporary array that contains your parameters:

```
my @temp_array = ( -host => server, -user => bob, -more => [ -c => "cypher" ] );
```

Now, you can pass this array directly to the constructor:

```
my $ftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new( @temp_array );
```

What this allows you to do is to Dump `@temp_array` to see if it contains the parameters in the correct format:

```
say Dumper \@temp_array;
```

The output should look something like this:

```
VAR1 = {
    -host => "server",
    -user => "bob"
    -more => {
        -c => "cypher"
    }
}
```

Or, something like this (After all, this was an ARRAY reference):

```
 VAR = [
    "-host",
    "server",
    "-user",
    "bob",
    "-more",
    [
       "-c",
       "cypher",
    ],
]
```

Either way, I can see that my parameters are being passed correctly to the constructor. If there's still a problem with Net::SFTP::Foreign, I can probably eliminate my parameter passing as the issue. Instead, the issue might be due to other problems. For example, the issue may be due to the way the class uses my `ssh` command line function. (Yes, this class uses the *external* command!). This means if I am on a Windows system, and I didn't install a `ssh` client, my program may not work.